# DRF SessionAuthentication login page insecurity?

Tags: django, security, django-rest-framework

In the Django Rest Framework [SessionAuthentication documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) it says that

> **Warning**: Always use Django's standard login view when creating login pages. This will ensure your login views are properly protected.

Why should I use Django's standard login views on login pages? If I would like to make my own login views (for example, in React, Vue or Angular), what I should take into account to make the view "as secure as the Django's standard login view"?

Comment: Not adding this as an answer because I don't have anything specific.  But I think its just a little lazy to say always use.  If you always use it, then you know you haven't invalidated security best practices.  However, you could absolutely still maintain security without "always using Django's standard login view".  Some extra details: https://hackernoon.com/5-ways-to-make-django-admin-safer-eb7753698ac8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's a bit strangely worded. This is related to `django.contrib.auth.views`. Within these there is a `login()` function and this login function is meant as Django's standard login view.

[How to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) part of documentation in Django describes how `login()` should be used.

> To log a user in, from a view, use `login()`. It takes an `HttpRequest` object and a User object. `login()` saves the user’s ID in the session, using Django’s session framework.

There is also a login example code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

You can still implement your own login system, but in most cases you will still be using Django's `login()` to actually log a user in. You can check `login()` source code [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#login) to see how it's implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the warning actually says just that "whenever logging in, be sure to use [django.contrib.auth:login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#login)"? I still don't get the point why this warning is added only to SessionAuthentication documentation. The [TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) docs do not have this warning, for example.

Comment: I'm starting to think that they might be actually referring to "Login CSRF" attacks, but I'm not sure how it is related to the django.contrib.auth:login-view. What other "protection" you might need when logging in?

Comment: When it comes to SessionAuthentication, Django and DRF session are the same. When you login to Django, you login to DRF as well. With TokenAuthentication clients authenticate by passing the token key in the "Authorization" HTTP header.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm correct, when using TokenAuthentication, [Token](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#generating-tokens) objects (strings) are attached to every user, when a user is created. After that, user may log in by passing the correct Token in a HTTP Request Header called 'Authorization'. But of course, at some point user needs to send username&password to the server (to relogin), and then you must first use SessionAuthentication to log the user in and send the Token to the user's browser/front end client.

Comment: You don't need to use session. Session is not created, because the user is never logged in. Username and password are only used to obtain token. First user is authenticated by calling `authenticate(username=username, password=password)` and if successful, Token is obtained.

Answer (score 3):

I went down the rabbit hole, and here's what I found out.

## "Django's standard login view"

There is actually a view called `login` in `django.contrib.auth.views` ([source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/df41b5a05d4e00e80e73afe629072e37873e767a/django/contrib/auth/views.py)). When used, it calls `LoginView.as_view()(request)`, from the same module. This actually uses the [`login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#login) function from django.contrib.auth (imported as `auth_login`). Since `LoginView` is a Class Based View, its [dispatch method will be called](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views). Looking from the source, few layers of protection can be detected.

1. [`django.views.decorators.debug.sensitive_post_parameters`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.decorators.debug.sensitive_post_parameters): When called without parameters, will hide any post parameters replacing them with stars (`********`). This allows sensitive information, such as the username and password, to be filtered out of reports when an error occurs .
2. [`django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_protect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_protect): Provides CSRF protection. For example, when using CSRF cookies, compares the `csrftoken` cookie to the a) Hidden CSRF input form field or b) `X-CSRFTOKEN` HTTP Request Header. This helps mitigating [CSRF Login attacks](https://support.detectify.com/customer/portal/articles/1969819-login-csrf).
3. [`django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache): Add  `Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` to the HTTP Response Header. I'm pretty sure this has also something to do with safety.

In addition, to the `get_redirect_url` method of the LoginView, there is comment `Return the user-originating redirect URL if it's safe.`, so there is possibly yet another safety-layer, but I could not see how it makes the redirection URL "safe".

### What I should take into account to make a view "as secure as the Django's standard login view"?

Based on the layers of protection in the django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView, at least the following should be considered:

1. Hiding sensitive post parameters (from error logs), using the `sensitive_post_parameters` -decorator.
2. Login form CSRF protection
3. Preventing caching of the HttpResponse of succesful login
4. When redirecting after login, ensuring that the url is safe.

Comment: did you ever actually interface with the auth system from a mobile app? That's what I'm trying to do now since token auth has it's own security issues, but reading material on using django's auth system outside the browser is sparse.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I only worked with a browser based mobile app.